# Swagger not producing json file for the second method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-web-api2

Ok I have one controller and two functions but when I try to go to swagger in the url I get failed to load the json file but I figure its to do with multiple actions being the same

Error Produced

> Fetch errorInternal Server Error /swagger/v1/swagger.json

I tried this line suggested by another so quesiton

> c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions =>
>   apiDescriptions.First());

But then that hid the method from the swagger docs view so how would a person be able to test them. Is there something wrong I am doing in my controller.

```
public class BmiInformationsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppManagerDBContext _context;

    public BmiInformationsController(AppManagerDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<BmiInformation>>> GetBmiInformation() {
        return await _context.BmiInformation.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/BmiInformations
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<BmiInformation>>> GetBmiInformationByUserId(string id)
    {
        return await _context.BmiInformation.Where(w => w.TennentId == new Guid(id)).ToListAsync();
    }        
}
```

This is how I have my swagger configured

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
   c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "App Manager - Running Buddies", Version = "v1" });
   c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());

   c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
   Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
   Name = "Authorization",
   In = ParameterLocation.Header,
   Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
   Scheme = "bearer",
   BearerFormat = "JWT"

 });
```

My Routes in my start-up file.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add explicit routes with `[Route]`-attribute above controller and action methods as following:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
public class BmiInformationsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppManagerDBContext _context;

    public BmiInformationsController(AppManagerDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("bmi/all")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<BmiInformation>>> GetBmiInformation() {
        return await _context.BmiInformation.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/BmiInformations
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("bmi/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<BmiInformation>>> GetBmiInformationByUserId(string id)
    {
        return await _context.BmiInformation.Where(w => w.TennentId == new Guid(id)).ToListAsync();
    }        
}
```

When setting explicit routes, there are no more conflicting actions and swagger can show both actions.

You can also remove `c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());` (this is why second method was not included in swagger.json, you took only first in case of route conflict).

Comment: Actually that didnt work same error occoured with two even though added same as above.

Comment: Updated my answer, try this!

Comment: that did the trrick thank makes since that they cant have the same paths like.

Comment: Good to hear @rogue39nin !

Comment: I always forget about routes but it does make total since.